# Is there a way to better way I can speed up this stored procedure

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

I would like to know if there is a way I can better write or filter this stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `update_blank_holiday_record`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE finished INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE temp_staff_record_key VARCHAR(45);
    DECLARE temp_shift_date DATE;
    DECLARE temp_update_type INT;
    
    DECLARE staff_shift_result CURSOR FOR ((SELECT DISTINCT `staff_record_key`, `shift_date`, 0 FROM `staff_shift_holiday` WHERE (`shift_day_template_record_key` = 'HOL') UNION SELECT `staff_record_key`, `shift_date`, 1 FROM `pending_update_staff_balance` WHERE (!ISNULL(`shift_date`))) ORDER BY `shift_date` ASC);
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
    
    
    OPEN staff_shift_result;
    get_staff_shift:LOOP
        START TRANSACTION;
        FETCH staff_shift_result INTO temp_staff_record_key, temp_shift_date, temp_update_type;
        IF finished = 1 THEN
            LEAVE get_staff_shift;
        END IF;
        IF temp_update_type = 0 THEN
            SELECT `shift_date` INTO temp_shift_date FROM `staff_shift_holiday`WHERE (`staff_record_key` = temp_staff_record_key AND `shift_day_template_record_key` = 'HOL') ORDER BY `shift_date` ASC LIMIT 1;
        END IF;
        CALL UPDATE_HOLIDAY_RECORD(temp_staff_record_key, temp_shift_date);
        CALL UPDATE_STAFF_BALANCE(temp_staff_record_key);
        IF temp_update_type = 1 THEN
            DELETE FROM `pending_update_staff_balance` WHERE (`staff_record_key` = temp_staff_record_key) ORDER BY `record_id` ASC;
        END IF;
        COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE staff_shift_result;
END
```

What does this procedure do:
When I assign a national holiday to a staff. First the record gets registered with the shift record_key 'HOL-'. The stored procedure checks which national holiday has the user taken and assigns the correct holiday that follows(e.g national day, independence day etc) and inserts the correct record key, e.g HOL-34FEC.
I have an event that is recurring every 5 minutes, and sometimes the query takes a long time and my whole application freezes. I can not register new records in the database. The event takes almost 300 seconds to complete.
Here is the -slow.log file

```
# Time: 2023-11-28T21:54:18.288680+08:00
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost [localhost]  Id: 147871
# Schema: test Last_errno: 0  Killed: 0
# Query_time: 256.991099  Lock_time: 0.000000  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 66829634  Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 0
# Stored_routine: test.update_blank_holiday
use test;
SET timestamp=1701179658;
CALL update_blank_holiday_record();
```

Edit: I have triggers in my `staff_shift` table. Here is the initialize trigger for HOL. How can I implement here so it checks out the follow-up holiday (and the correct key).

```
ELSEIF NEW.`shift_day_template_record_key` LIKE "HOL%" THEN
        SET NEW.`shift_day_template_calendar_label` = "Holiday";
        SET NEW.`shift_type` = 'Leave';
        SET NEW.`s1_in` = NULL;
        SET NEW.`s1_out` = NULL;
        SET NEW.`s2_in` = NULL;
        SET NEW.`s2_out` = NULL;
        SET NEW.`shift_total_hours` = 0;
        SET NEW.`shift_day_template_hex_color_code` = (SELECT holiday_hex_color_code FROM setting WHERE (property_record_key = NEW.`property_record_key` AND record_status = 'Active'));
        SET NEW.`shift_day_template_on_in_lieu` = "No";
        INSERT INTO `staff_shift_holiday` (`staff_shift_record_key`, `staff_record_key`, `shift_date`, `shift_day_template_record_key`) VALUES (NEW.`record_key`, NEW.`staff_record_key`, NEW.`shift_date`, NEW.`shift_day_template_record_key`) AS NEW
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `staff_shift_record_key` = NEW.`record_key`, `shift_day_template_record_key` = NEW.`shift_day_template_record_key`;
    END IF;
```

Edit #2: Here is the how the data looks on my table (1 user).

| shift_day_template_record_key | shift_day_template_short_code | shift_day_template_display_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| HOL | NULL | NULL |
| HOL-4C36A | SH10 | Independence Day |
| HOL-886F4 | SH9 | National Day |
| HOL-CC142 | SH8 | Christmas Day |

I tried altering the  event to not run that frequently, but to run overnight instead. Next i tried filtering the procedure to get only a certain number of records. But I really need the procedure to run frequently, because everytime I get emails from my client telling me why is the holiday not showing.

Comment: You iterate 60kk rows one-by-one.. Also you call 2 procedures for each iteration.. of course this is slow. Use solid queries instead of cursor.

Comment: did you consider a trigger or 2?

Comment: @Akina, can you give me an example based on my stored procedure. Thank you.

Comment: @P.Salmon I did not know that you can add triggers in stored procedures.

Comment: not to procedures to tables..

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes I have triggers in my `staff_shift` table. Please check out my edited post.

Comment: Hey tuneup90 can you post some sample data with the expected result? Just reading the logic I don't see why this needs to be procedural with cursors. But could be missing something.

Comment: @Tuneup90, I totally could help you out on this, but I'm very confused as to why you're doing this one record at a time.  As Error_2646 says, maybe a data set example of how it starts and how it needs to look at the end would really help.

Comment: @Error_2646 I added the columns on how the table looks like.

Comment: Lots of comments saying similar things.  1. Easy fix - don't commit on every record.  Move your Transaction Start and your Commit outside your loop - start transaction, loop your cursor, commit.  2. Harder fix - rewrite this to not use a cursor at all - Start Transaction, update holiday_record, update staff_balance, delete from pending, Commit.

Comment: @QuestionGuyBob I edited my question and illustrated how the table looks like when a stored procedures has run and the first column is when the stored procedure has not run.

Comment: the cursor references 2 tables but you describe and sample only 1. even with a cursor I would expect reasonable performance if a small subset of the data is loaded to the cursor , but there are no metrics supplied ,no table definitions, no code supplied for called procedures, no explain plan for the code blocks. You should be able to check performance by running the individual elements eg the cursor select, the cursor loop etc to narrow down the issue.